# I have tried everything I can to substract weight on this region, but it doesn't work

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

Video demonstration: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EXeZLDfJwBFIgf956f4iZ9kB3FNC2h4uM0zNq-hCBwYEfA?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=lnQncN

Is there any alternative solution? I tried increasing/ decreasing radius, weight, strength and toggling off subdiv, but nothing works

[image]

Comment: Hello, you have activated the Vertex Selection option (top left) which means that you'll only be able to act on the selected vertices, have you tried to see if it works if you disable this option (or select the wanted vertices in Edit mode). If it still doesn't work please share your file